# How can I make laravel casting array on the model?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, laravel-5.3

I try like this

Data type of votes_detail in database is json

My model like this :

```
<?php
class Store extends Model{  
    protected $fillable = [ ...,'votes_detail',...];
    protected $casts = [
        'votes_detail' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

My controller like this :

```
$store = Store::find($id)
$votes_detail = $store->votes_detail;
dd($votes_detail);
```

The result of dd($votes_detail) is :

> {"1": "1", "5": "2"}

Why the result is still json?

The result should be an array

Whereas I've set the array in cast model

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: i think your model is fine. you just have to access the property directly (eg. `$store->votes_detail->1`). when you try to assign it to a variable, it won't work anymore since its not part of the model context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it by converting your data to the array by using `toArray()` function. So it should be like

```
$store = Store::find($id)->toArray();
```

//$store contain a array.

```
$votes_detail = $store['votes_detail'];
```

make it  `dd($votes_detail)` and get your desire result.

Comment: I want to set it through cast model

Comment: You can learn something about `https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections` &
`https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-toarray`

Comment: happy to know that, my answer is helpful for you.

Comment: Converting the whole model to array is not optimal in my opinion. You could check out Model accessors and mutators to manipulate attributes before accessing them and before storing them on DB

Answer (score 4):

You could use Laravel [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor). In you model define a method called exactly `getVotesDetailAttribute($details)`:

```
public function getVotesDetailAttribute($details)
{
    return json_decode($details, true);
}
```

then when you will call `$store->votes_detail` you will get the expected result.

After that you can use [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) to convert an array back to JSON when it is saved back in the DB. Define the method `setVotesDetailAttribute($value)` as follows:

```
public function setVotesDetailsAttribute($value)
{
     $this->attributes['votes_detail'] = json_encode($value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are storing array data after `json_encode()` to a column which is not defined as `json()` in the migration like:

```
$table->text('votes_detail');
```

or

```
$table->integer('votes_detail');
```

And seems you have defined `votes_detail` as string, number or something else.

This is the reason behind your problem. So, define column type as `json` in migration like:

```
$table->json('votes_detail');
```

And then refresh your migration, your casting in the model will work and you will get your desired array.